# how to use value of one switch case in another switch case: value is Scanner inputs?

Tags: java

I have two nested switches and I wanted to use value of one switch case in another switch case. As in the below example, I wanted to use the double variable **temp_usr** and pass it as an argument to a method **(cels())** in the another switch case, how can I do this?

```
switch( switch1){
case 1: 
{
System.out.println(" You have selected Celsius");
Scanner temp_ip= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the temperature in celsius");
double temp_usr= temp_ip.nextDouble();
}   
break;
case 2: ...............
case 3: ...............

switch(switch2) {
case 1: 
{
System.out.println("convert it into Celsius");
System.out.println(cels(arg));  /*this argument should take value of temp_usr*/
}
break;
case 2: .........  
case 3: .........
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this? I suggest you fix the formatting to make it easier to read.

Comment: Well what would you expect to happen if `switch1` is 2 but `switch2` is 1?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is visible inside the block it is defined. If you want to open the visibility declare it outside the switch. Try this:

```
double temp_usr= 0.0; //declaring here switch will make it visible in the following code
switch( switch1){
case 1: 
{
System.out.println(" You have selected Celsius");
Scanner temp_ip= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the temperature in celsius");
temp_usr= temp_ip.nextDouble();
}   
break;
case 2: ...............
case 3: ...............

switch(switch2) {
case 1: 
{
System.out.println("convert it into Celsius");
System.out.println(cels(arg));  /*this argument should take value of temp_usr*/
}
break;
case 2: .........  
case 3: .........
```

Comment: Don't do the user's homework for them, even if it's a skeleton of code...

Comment: it worked..that was a good catch..i will keep it in mind..
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all those aren't nested switches.

Make sure the default case also results in an accessible `temp_usr`. First of all, I'd declare it outside the switch statement for scope reasons:

```
double temp_usr=0;
```

I would set it in each case block, and allow `default` to keep `0`.

Then, it will be available, valid, and in scope without a compiler error for the second switch statement.

Comment: thanks for the reply... here I have just written a piece of code..
I am trying it your way.